# Node.js AES decryption of Base64 String

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, google-cloud-functions

I'm decrypting messages from `Firebase` that is being sent to a `Firebase function`.

I'm quite new with encryption. But i'm using `AES-256`, with a static `IV` (i'm aware that not having a random iv isn't the best solution).

but i'm getting the correct results on both `Android` and `iOS` but not in `node.js`.

The message is Base64 encoded

this is my code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const cryptoKey = "MyEncryptionKey1MyEncryptionKey1";
const text = "Cidor8Ph7pZqPw0x2AwIKw=="

let messageToDecrypt = new Buffer(text, "utf8")
let key = new Buffer(cryptoKey, "utf8");
var decipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
var decoded = decipher.update(messageToDecrypt,'base64','utf-8');
decoded += decipher.final('utf-8');
text = decoded
console.log(decoded
```

The code compiles and runs, but it gives me a mumbo-jumbo answer that looks similar to this `�ŴC�p�-Q�)�1H&�8pD}5�i��ǁ�g`

Any ideas on how to improve this code?

Comment: if you're deciphering you should use `crypto.createDecipheriv`

Comment: How are you sure your key and decipher is created/finished before you call update ? Does it run sync ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What immediately jumps out to me is that you aren't creating your `messageToDecrypt` Buffer correctly.  You are writing:

```
const text = "Cidor8Ph7pZqPw0x2AwIKw=="
let messageToDecrypt = new Buffer(text, "utf8")
```

Which means, make a Buffer, the text I'm giving you is **utf8** encoded.  It **isn't** utf8 encoded, it is **base64** encoded.

So you should use:

```
const text = "Cidor8Ph7pZqPw0x2AwIKw=="
let messageToDecrypt = Buffer.from(text, "base64")
```

---

Consider the difference in Buffers that the encoding makes:

```
> Buffer.from(text, "utf8");
<Buffer 43 69 64 6f 72 38 50 68 37 70 5a 71 50 77 30 78 32 41 77 49 4b 77 3d 3d>
> Buffer.from(text, "base64");
<Buffer 0a 27 68 af c3 e1 ee 96 6a 3f 0d 31 d8 0c 08 2b>
```